# C# Web Application Razor Pages Camera Connection Static object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, web-applications, singleton, razor-pages

I'm trying to find a way to declare an object from a custom class that will connect to a camera and grab periodically an image. I have managed to do so by using a singleton and works perfectly.

Now I'm thinking how could I implement the same but say I want to connect to 5 cameras but I don't want each client to create its' own connection. Basically how would you implement a class that you can create multiple objects from but not create a new object each time a request comes through in Web API/Razor pages (both are implemented)

Thank you all!

Comment: You can init the 5 object in custom class, and write a function  to return the object based on your requirement.